# List all mp3 files having over 320 kbps bitrate using bash

Tags: grep, find, mp3, exif

I'd like to get a list of all mp3 files with >320 bitrate. I'm not sure, how to apply the regular expression to the output of exiftool -AudioBitrate command.

```
find . -type f -name '*.mp3' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' i; do
   BITRATE=echo $(exiftool -AudioBitrate "$i")| grep -q '#([0-9]+) kbps#';
   if $BITRATE > 320
      then echo $BITRATE "$i"
   fi
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a bash script that works. It is basically what you have with a few tweaks:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
set -o pipefail

find . -type f -name "*.mp3" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    BITRATE=$(exiftool -AudioBitrate "$file" | grep -Eo '[0-9]+ kbps' | sed 's/ kbps//')
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]] && [[ $BITRATE -ge 320 ]]; then
        echo $BITRATE "$file"
    fi
done
```

In setting the `$BITRATE` variable I run `exiftool` through a pipe directly and use `$(...)` to capture the output. Then, in the conditional I check if the `exiftool` -> `grep` pipe was successful and the bitrate is sufficiently high using Bash's numeric comparison operators.

I've checked that it handles some random `.mp3` files I have lying around, including ones with spaces in the name.

Comment: Thanks! It works well

Answer (score 2):

No need for all those tools...

```
exiftool -q -if '$AudioBitrate > 320' -p '$AudioBitrate $Directory/$Filename' -ext mp3 -r .
```

`exiftool`  searches recursively in the current directory, only files with `mp3` extension, and prints the bitrate and filename if the condition `$AudioBitrate > 320` is satisfied

Comment: Wow, nice ! Should be accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Simple and lazy way:

```
#!/bin/bash

bitrateMin=320
find . -iname '*.mp3' -print0 |
  while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    [[ $(exiftool -AudioBitrate "$file" | awk -v br="$bitrateMin" '$4 >= br{print $4}') ]] && printf '%s\n' "$file"
done
```